# How do I access and manipulate one file at a time in the getSelectedFiles() method?

Tags: java, foreach

So I am trying to create a music player widget but having problems playing multiple selected songs one at a time. I was hoping the enhanced for loop would iterate through all the files selected and play them one at a time but its playing all the songs at the same time. Is there a better way to make this work?

```
FileInputStream FIS;
BufferedInputStream BIS;

public Player player;
public long pauseLocation;
public long songTotalLength;
public boolean playState = false;
public String fileLocation;

public boolean playState(){
    return playState;
}

public void setPlayState(boolean value){
    this.playState = value;
}
public void select() {

    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MP3 Files", "mp3", "mpeg3");
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("D:\\MAIN_DIV\\Music");
    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        stop();

        if (playState == false) {
            File[] selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
            for (File x : selectedFile) {
                String song = x + "";
                String name = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
                display.setText(name);
                play(song);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void play(String path){

    playState();
        try {
            FIS = new FileInputStream(path);
            BIS = new BufferedInputStream(FIS);
            player = new Player(BIS);
            songTotalLength = FIS.available();
            fileLocation = path + "";
            //System.out.println(path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | JavaLayerException ex) {

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }



    new Thread (){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            if(playState == false){

                try {
                        player.play(); //play from start or resume


                    if (player.isComplete() && MusicPlayer.count==1){
                        play(fileLocation); 


                    }
                    if (player.isComplete()){
                        MusicPlayer.display.setText("");
                    }

                } catch (JavaLayerException ex) {

                }
            }    
        }
    }.start();
    setPlayState(false);

}
```

Comment: There is nothing with the for-loop as such. The problem is `play`. From your question it is not clear what play does but it probably creates a background process to play the song and returns while the song is playing letting the loop continue to pick up new songs. If you display the source code of `play`,we might help you on that. Additionally: what is playlist? Couldn't you run the playlist after the for-loop?

Comment: Okay. So that's  the source code for play. I removed the playlist class from the code (still working on that). Maybe now I can get some more help

Comment: I was hoping the loop would only continue after the play method was done with a song

Answer (score 0):

This is the cause of the problem:

```
new Thread () { ... } .start();
```

creates a thread that runs in background to play the song. The `play` method  returns while the song is playing letting the `for`-loop continue to pick up new songs.

It should work as expected, if you just keep the body of your `run`-method. That way, song playing is sequentially and `play` blocks until `player.play();` is done.

Comment: Keep the body of my run method? I don't think I really understand that.

Comment: The head of a method is the declarative part (i.e. public void run()), the body of a method is everything in between its curly braces. For a start, remove the whole thread code (`new Thread () { ... }.start();`) and replace it with just: `player.play();`.

Comment: The Thread allows the process to operate in the background. Removing it caused all other futures to be ineffective while a song was still playing

Comment: I will try and find a way around this though because the songs play one at a time now. But I will appreciate any more info though.